# Translating French Academic Titles to English

Tags: translations

I am an International student who's planning to continue his graduate studies in Canada, my referee who goes by the title "Enseignant-Chercheur" [1] taught me in a Statistics tutorial class and agreed to write a letter of recommendation on my behalf, the university I'm applying to asks me to enter my referee's title but I do not know what is the most appropriate translation for the above mentioned academic rank, the literal translation is "Teacher-Researcher," but the problem is does such title even exist or make any sense in an North American (and other English speaking countries) context? Should I translate the title? If so, what would be the most appropriate translation? And if not, should I just enter it without translation?

[1] https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enseignant-chercheur

Comment: Einsegnant-chercheur is a researcher actively doing research and having teaching duties. Administratively s/he depend on a university. In my country s/he would be titled as researcher and called prof by the student. This is not a translation but might help to find one, if really necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just use it as is.

In the US, if I search for the formal title I get sent to the French Wikipedia site. Even with my limited French (long ago and far away) I can understand the meaning. In particular, that it is a "superior" title, implying the doctorate or equivalent has been earned.

Some people and in some places there is sensitivity about titles. In general, I'd suggest being, yourself, sensitive to that.

My conclusion from a perusal of the Wikipedia is that it is similar to what we would here call a "professor", but maybe not a "Professor". The former is a job description, the latter is a title and the title may mean different things in different places. But the job description is likely enough.

And, of course, it isn't primarily a language question at all. There are different academic traditions in different countries and words (simple phrases) aren't always subtle enough for the differences.

And, of course, in some parts of Canada, French is the preferred language.

A funny story just appeared in the news. A woman from France was denied something like "permanent residence" in Quebec because her French wasn't deemed "good enough."

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Buffy, so I better not translate it then, right?

Comment: That seems best, to me at least.

Comment: Right I commented too early. Plus 1